# How would humans adapt to extreme climates

Tags: humans, earth-like, genetics, species

I have a situation when urbanites without any useful survival skills (bankers, marketers, curators, sociologists, etc) are mysteriously brought on a Earth like planet. They have to revert to hunting and gathering in order to survive. The plants and animals are edible.

The planet has an extreme seasonal variations, in summer temperature goes up to 58°C like Libya,  while in winter it goes down to -90°C like Antarctica.

How would the descendants of this group biologically differ from us after 10,000 years?

Comment: They will likely all die in the first winter. - But seriously. First: Hello and welcome to WB.SE, it's always good to see an influx of new avatars. Your question shows promise, but as of now any answer to it would have to be **huge** in order to address what you're asking. And that's the main issue: On here, our main goal is to create a database of questions and answers in order to help others that face similar problems. Good questions hence should be as precise as possible so to provoke good, concise, helpful answers. Please have a look at other questions and maybe the tour :D

Comment: @dot_Sp0T: I'd seriously doubt that they'd even survive until winter.

Comment: Agree with @dot_Sp0T.  And for ease here is a link to the [help]

Answer (score 2):

ZERO survival skills? Really? Nothing at all beyond the basic "don't drink dirty water" and "cook your food" stuff that children learn?

In that case, they probably all die. Hunting is really, really hard, especially in pounding heat with little available water. Gathering will work (sort of) for the summer, but they'll starve in the winter. They wouldn't even get a chance to start farming. Even if a few of them survive, there's gonna be a hell of a population bottleneck - their descendants would either be nonexistent, or so inbred that they'll never survive.

Answer (score 2):

**After 10.000 years? Barely at all**. Unless the planet diffferse in things like gravity. Bar a vastly different environment we won't change a whole lot in 10.000 year. That's the time between us and the stone age.

Their dietary requirements would change. We have evidence that our diet will leave an impact within a few Thousand years. That's how large groups of us became lactose tolerant. How the Inuit became able to survive on a fatty diet.

But that's not a visible change. We already had farming 10.000 years ago. In your time period you likely get some different groups by inbreeding like red hair among the modern day Irish. But that's about the extend of it.

Comment: That is, if they survive to reproduce. Given that summer are Libya-like and winters are Antarctic-like, I seriously doubt that hunting and gathering would produce enough calories to avoid starvation...

Comment: Oh totally but he wasn't asking if they'd survive. So I figured I explain why little would happen anyway.